# CloudKit Data Transfer Limits

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud, cloudkit

I am investigating what may be the best choice of cloud database service would be for my app. I am closely looking at CloudKit, however one thing concerns me. The Public Database transfer limits being 250kb per day with an additional 5kb per user.

What is the best way to measure how much I am transferring in and out of my app? I see this as the biggest issue with CloudKit, as there are no analytics provided on this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there aren't any analytics to view usage. If you notice that your users are bumping into the limits you should [contact Apple](https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit.php) and they'll work with you to bump the limits.

Note that if you use the private database that data is counted against the individual users quota and not against your app. Every iCloud user gets 5GB of storage for free (shared with backups, photo streams, etc), and users can purchase additional storage if they want.